# Using Kaa middleware for IOT projects

Tags: iot, kaa

Want to build a real time apps with Kaa, as it is a open source middleware. Walked through their documentation and get diverted easily into multiple things and unable to get a information on how to write Kaa sdk into a sensor or a gateway (or) using Kaa API in sensors and gateways

If someone had done this, you are welcome to guide me

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Your first Kaa application](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/) documentation and Sandbox samples?

Please describe your question in more details.